# Where is my Java SDK 7u7 installed?

Tags: java

I downloaded and installed Java 1.7 from [this site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html).

When I run the Java Control Panel, I could check I have it correctly installed.

[image]

However, when I checked the Java version from command line, the version that I use is Java 1.6.

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_33"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_33-b03-424-11M3720)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.8-b03-424, mixed mode)
```

The system directory doesn't have the 1.7.

[image]

What's wrong with this?

- Where is the Java 1.7 is installed?
- How can I make the Java 1.7 as default Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found Java 1.7 SDK in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk`, and all the binaries in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_07.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`.

[image]

And by clicking the jdk file, I could arrange the order so that Java SE 7 is executed first.

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

And I could also bring up the app from /Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences.app

[image]

For eclipse, I could add one line in `/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini` to teach eclipse what Java it will use :

```
-vm
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home/bin/java
```

Comment: You really didn't give anyone much time to provide an answer eh? Good to know though

Comment: This answer is great if you have the JDK installed.  But what if you only have the JRE installed?  Nothing shows up in `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.